# jUpgrade stops at "Checking and cleaning"

Tags: migration, upgrade, joomla1.5, joomla2.5

I want to upgrade from Joomla 1.5.26 to 2.5 and have problems with jUpgrade.

jUpgrade stops at "Checking and cleaning", see screenshot. No error message.

[image: jUpgrade]

cURL is enabled.

root tmp directory is writable.

Mootools Upgrade is enabled.

Tested in Firefox and Chrome with JavaScript enabled.

Folders that not is writable in Help >> System Information >> Directory Permissions:

components/

modules/

plugins/

plugins/content/

plugins/editors/

plugins/editors-xtd/

plugins/search/

plugins/system/

plugins/user/

plugins/xmlrpc/

templates/

Log Directory ($log_path) /home/agslosite/public_html/agslosite.se/logs/

Comment: Check your server error logs, i'm sure you'll find some errors in there.

Answer (score 4):

Try go to jUpgrade settings and enable both 'debug' options.

I had to add write permissions to public_html and group write (that is apache) to the whole site. Also I created (joomlaroot)/jupgrade folder manually and set proper permissions to it.

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered this on a couple Joomla 1.5 sites using jUpgrade. Manually creating the jupgrade folder and chmodding it to 777 has fixed this "checking and cleaning" hang-up every time.